# Looking for proper android element

Tags: android, layout, element, android-designer

I'm looking for an android element, which is very similar to collapsing toolbar but upside down. An example is showed in images. Please help me to find the proper solution for the related design.

[element like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQDBl.png)

[element like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLQK4.png)

Comment: That's a custom bottom sheet https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom

Comment: @javdromero Yeah, I see. Thanks a lot!